# copy-paste issue when using SSMS over GoToMyPC

Tags: copy-paste, ssms, cut-and-paste, gotomypc

I'm hoping someone here has run into this issue and knows if there's a fix for it.

When using GoToMyPC, I'm unable to copy text from the editor in SSMS (v14) on my remote desktop and paste it into the editor on SSMS running on the company desktop. Same problem in the opposite direction, from company to remote.

Yet I have no problem copying text from Notepad on my remote desktop and pasting it into the SSMS editor on my company desktop, and no problem doing the same in the opposite direction.

I'd like to avoid having to take that intermediary step of pasting into Notepad.

The behavior is the same whether the keyboard shortcuts are used or menu copy.

Comment: Does restarting the `RDPClip service` on either/both sides, resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't see a service named RDPClip (or anything similar) in the Services listing on either machine.

Comment: Odd. I've been using this Notepad intermediary approach for over a year and suddenly, after posting this question, even that  no longer works. I can't even paste from Notepad to Notepad between machines.

Comment: Perhaps the lack of `RDPClip` is to blame. Someone may have removed the service, although that seems a bit extreme.